# Git relative path issue - no lintable files found at paths

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, git-diff, swiftlint

I have an iOS/Swift project under git version control system. Hierarchy is below,

```
home/user/git_root/docs
home/user/git_root/project
home/user/git_root/project/project.xcodeproj
```

As you see my `git_root` directory contains some other documents in `docs` folder along with actual project directory.

I have installed `swiftlint` in my Mac using homebrew,

```
brew install swiftlint
```

Current location of swiftlint installed is,

```
which swiftlint
/usr/local/bin/swiftlint
```

When I am running my below script which was added in `Build phase -> Run scripts`, Weird thing happens,

#### Script:

```
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
    echo "swiftlint already installed in machine";
    git diff --cached --name-only | grep "\.swift" | while read filename; do
        echo "swiftlinting file $filename";
        swiftlint lint --path "$filename";
    done
fi
```

#### Issue:

Some swift files are printed by echo, but `swiftlint` cant find the files and produces below error,

> No lintable files found at paths : ''

For example, below is the output from build log,

> swiftlinting file project/a.swift
>
> No lintable files found at paths : 'project/a.swift

But when I apply `cd home/user/git_root` at the beginning of the script, it works perfectly. But I cannot know the actual root of the git because other teammates might rename it on their own and so, I cannot use hardcoded path in script.

Why `git diff` produces file paths which are not recognised by `swiftlint` from the same directory in script? How can I solve this problem?

#### Optional info:

The purpose of the script is to run swiftlint only in newly modified unstaged swift files. Also note that I am **not** using any `.swiftlint.yaml` files for swiftlint configurations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the --path argument only takes absolute paths. I don't know how you can make it take a relative path, but you can slightly alter the script to append the rest of the path to the filename, like this:

```
git diff --cached --name-only | grep "\.swift" | while read filename; do
    echo "swiftlinting file $filename";
    swiftlint lint --path "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/${filename}";
done
```